# Microsoft Bot Framework V4 Appinsights related information ? How to use it for custom metric and custom events using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, appinsights

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics

About capturing custom variables using query than show a result on dashboard (Nodejs-javascript) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how do you capture those metrics and events from a nodejs application, this article should give you the answers you need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs.

If you have tried this and can't get it to work, please add additional details to your question and I can expand this answer.

Comment: yes it works... i am able to implement app-insights feature using nodejs-JavaScript.